# How to make two different programs wrote in different languages to link?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, linker

I and my friend are working on the same project which is a pretty big so we split the project. Everything is ok till now but the real problem is that my friend has written the code in C++ but I have written the code in python now some of the functions that I have written will depend on those that he wrote. Like if I wrote GUI of a calculator using python and the addition logic is written in C++.

How can we link this two programs to get the desired output?

Comment: You can use Python's C API to bridge both parts of your software. Also consider using a library that helps you with the bindings (otherwise it's a lot of tedious labour), e.g. PyBind11 or Boost Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possible solutions to this problem, depending on how complex your requirements are.

If it is possible to make a C wrapper for the C++ functions you want to call from the Python side, [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) may be an option. If the Python program needs access to a more complex C++ API, have look at [swig](http://www.swig.org/),  [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) or [PyBind11](https://pypi.org/project/pybind11/) (thanks to @lubgr for mentioning the latter). If the C++ code, however, is accessible through a command line program, and it is sufficient for your case to run it that way from Python, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python).